# Android Get specific id from listview using Firebase Database

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing one note application using firebase. As you can see in the first screenshot, i'm using custom listview to display all the data from firebase database.

[image]

After that i have a setOnItemLongClickListener to delete a selected item from listview. So when i longpress on an item i have this AlertDialog menu.

[image]

So, next i have to press 'YES' button and delete the selected item from listView.

This is my setOnItemLongClickListener code

```
mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete List?");
            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                }
            });

            dialogBuilder.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is the ListAdapter class

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post>{

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Post> objects){
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false);
    }

    TextView listName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_date);
    TextView body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_body);

    Post list =  getItem(position);

    listName.setText(list.getTitle());
    date.setText(list.getDate());
    body.setText(list.getBody());

    //checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    return convertView;
}
```

}

```
    mDatabase.child(getUid()).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            mAdapter.add(post);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
    });
```

And this is my Firebase database

[image]

The problem is that i am not able to get the id for the specific longpressed item to delete it.

For example if i longpress in the first item i wanna get the id
-KiFDsP6qOUAo6hw_ES0. Can any one help me how can i do that?

Comment: You should have model class to store the data for different ids and then use that model class to get the data. Can you show the code in which you are sending data to adapter.?

Answer (score 3):

1. First modify your class and add an attribute Parent of type string and when you add your data to database setValue of Parent to parent Value
   2.When you are retrieving data from firebase you must be storing them in ArrayList kind of data structure let the Variable be myList of arraylist type 
   then on listView try this 
   mListview.setOnItemSelected Listener 
   you will get the position of your item then use that position to get the object from arraylist from the object

   3. Now get the Objects Parent Value and setthat to null